Dynamically select an email based on a value in a DE
I have a request to select the email at time of send based on the asset ID within a DE. The number of asset IDs may change but it is deterministic. (value = 504). I am unaware how to do this using ampscript so curious how to go about this ask.

An email send involves more than just the recipient data and template-based email. It also requires configuration in the send definition (e.g. Send Classification, Subject, CC, click tracking, etc.). Because of this, I don't believe you can achieve your goal using just AMPscript.
The closest approach would be to create a Journey with a Decision Split, where you can configure each email send based on the criteria. However, keep in mind that if a new template-based email is added in the DE source, you will need to update the Journey to include and configure this new email.
